# Rails Autocomplete: function not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

i jave the following code

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
    new Ajax.Autocompleter('issue_autocomplete',
       'issue_candidates',
       '<%= url_for :controller => 'requirements', :action => 'autocomplete_issues' %>',
       { minChars: 1,
         frequency: 0.5,
         afterUpdateElement : function(text, li) { $('issue_id').setValue(li.id) }
         });
  <% end %>
```

and in my requirements_controller.rb file there is a autocomplete_issues function.

yet, when i type in some text into the textfield, it says 404 the function couldnt be found. i dont think it has to do something with the routes, because at another place in the code theres a autocompleteter calling a different function but using similar routes.

url: http://localhost:3000/requirements/autocomplete_issues

stacktrace:

Processing RequirementsController#autocomplete_issues (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-09 13:15:23) [POST]
  Parameters: {"sink_name"=>"sd", "action"=>"autocomplete_issues", "controller"=>"requirements"}
  ←[4;36;1mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT max("settings".updated_on) AS max_updated_on FROM "settings" ←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) AND (users.status = 1) AND ( ("users"."type" = 'User' OR "users"."type" =
'AnonymousUser' ) ) ←[0m
Filter chain halted as [:find_project] rendered_or_redirected.
Completed in 2156ms (View: 219, DB: 0) | 404 Not Found [http://localhost/requirements/autocomplete_issues]
ssues]

routes are regular map.resources without anything fancy

anyone has an idea where I could look?

Comment: Use firebug to check the URL that is being invoked, or your development log to see the request. Have you checked your routes? Post your stack trace for more help.

Comment: thanks. i added those infos to my top post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that jumps out to me is:

```
Filter chain halted as [:find_project] rendered_or_redirected
```

You probably have a before_filter that is requiring either :post , or an authenticated user, or some other precondition

Comment: yes. i just tried again with some modifications and now it isnt a 404 but a 403....now just to find out how to fix this